# Kubernetes Vetical Pod Autoscaler wont recreate pods

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, jupyter-notebooks

I'm running the Kubernetes VPA on a GKE project. It has Vertical Pod Autoscaling enabled and I've run the `vpa-up.sh` script from their Github [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/hack).

Furthermore, the pods running are JupyterHub notebook servers, which has been setup following: [Zero to Jupyterhub with Kubernetes](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They are created with 200m CPU limit and 100m CPU request:

As a test, I'm running an infinite for loop, printing the value every time, to get the CPU running.

When running the for loop in a notebook, the CPU usage quickly reaches the limit of 200m CPU. However the VPA never performs a scale, despite the `updateMode` being `Auto`. I've tried setting a `minAllowed` for the VPA, but that still doesn't trigger a rescale.

```
  ...
  resourcePolicy:
    containerPolicies:
    - containerName: '*'
      minAllowed:
        cpu: 400m
```

So when describing the pod and autoscaler, the output shows:

```
NAME             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
jupyter-pytest   1m           411Mi
```

```
  ...
  recommendation:
    containerRecommendations:
    - containerName: jupyter-pytest
      lowerBound:
        cpu: 400m
        memory: 500Mi
      target:
        cpu: 400m
        memory: 500Mi
      uncappedTarget:
        cpu: 25m
        memory: 262144k
      upperBound:
        cpu: 400m
        memory: "951510605"
```

How come it doesn't perform a scale, despite the usage being below the `lowerBound`?